# Embedded power bi visuals filters not updating

Tags: javascript, powerbi, powerbi-embedded

I am trying to update the filters on some embedded visuals but it is not working.
Also tried using this: `await visual.updateFilters(FiltersOperations.Add, filters, FiltersLevel.Report);` with no success. When using the `FiltersOperations.Add` and `FiltersLevel.Report` I get errors not able to find these, therefore tried to change them to their enum values, 2 for add, 0 for report.

```
let embedConfiguration = {
                    accessToken: "@ViewBag.Token",
                    embedUrl: "@ViewBag.EmbedUrl",
                    id: "@ViewBag.Id",
                    pageName: pageName,
                    tokenType: 1,
                    type: 'visual',
                    visualName: visualName
                };
                 
                // Get a reference to the HTML element that contains the embedded report.
                let embedContainer = $('#'+embedContainerName)[0];
                
                 
                
                const basicFilter = {
                                              $schema: "http://powerbi.com/product/schema#basic",
                                              target: {
                                                table: "Personskader",
                                                column: "Disiplin"
                                              },
                                              operator: "In",
                                              values: ["Insulation"],
                                              filterType: 1
                                            };
                // Embed the visual.
                let visual = powerbi.embed(embedContainer, embedConfiguration);
                await visual.updateFilters(2, basicFilter);
                }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is with type. Second argument will be of type IFilter[]. So, pass it in array and it will work.

You need to import `powerbi-models` when you are using `FiltersOperations.Add` this is the reason you are getting errors.You can specify `models.FiltersOperations.Add` and this works.

`await visual.updateFilters(models.FiltersOperations.Add, [basicFilter]);`

You can play with any Api and test it for your own report here https://playground.powerbi.com/en-us/dev-sandbox

References:
https://learn.microsoft.com/javascript/api/overview/powerbi/control-report-filters

Comment: I tried this, but it still isn't working. Do you see any errors when you skim through the latest answers code? I'm using powerbi-client v2.21.0. Shouldn't this be sufficient?
Thank you

Comment: You are facing errors when applying filters ? or with the Visual embed ? It worked fine for me. You can test your filters code by embedding your own visual here https://playground.powerbi.com/en-us/dev-sandbox

Comment: If you are facing error with visual embed, please once check the reference of html element   `let embedContainer = $('#embedContainer')[0];` . embedContainer should also be in string Ig

Comment: Facing errors when updating filters. It doesnt add filters at all when using visual.updateFilters. Thanks though. I am able to update filters if I do a new embed, while adding filters to the embedConfiguration, but seems unescessary to have to do that to every visual when the one-liner should be working.

Comment: Are we waiting for report to  get loaded before making any API call ?

Comment: Tried this too, but maybe I'm misplacing the code.. At the moment I'm using a workaround by embedding the visuals again when filters are added. I'm guessing this has downsides to it compared to using the updateFilters call? Thanks for your help though!